# Ĉu “Krei lingvon bazita sur …” aŭ “… bazitan sur …”?

Tags: grammar, accusative

Mi iam aŭdis la frazon “mi kreis lingvon bazita sur esperanto” kaj mi hezitas ĉu tiu uzo kun adjektivo sen akuzativo estas ĝusta. Mi emus argumenti ke la dua formo estas la ĝusta. Tamen eble oni povus subkompreni la unuan formon kiel “krei lingvon [kiu estas] bazita sur …”. Ĉu tia subkompreno eblas?

PMEG havas preskaŭ [similajn ekzemplojn](http://bertilow.com/pmeg/gramatiko/specialaj_priskriboj/perverba/objekto.html) sed tio parolas nur pri “perverba priskribo”:

> Vi farbas la domon ruĝa. = Vi farbas la domon tiel, ke ĝi fariĝas ruĝa.

En tiuj ekzemploj la verbo ŝanĝas la staton de io, aŭ precizigas la econ de io kio jam ekzistas. En ĉi tiu ekzemplo la ago de la verbo kreas la aĵon kaj ĝi tute ne ekzistis antaŭ tio, kaj tial ĝi ne ŝajnas al mi perverba priskribo.

Kiu estus la ĝusta formo?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Certe eblas perverba priskribo kun "krei": "Dio kreis la pekulojn senpekaj." Tio esprimas la ideon, ke la pekuloj estis senpekaj tuj post sia kreiĝo, kaj nur iĝis pekaj poste. Se oni akuzativigas "senpekaj", oni havas memkontraŭdiran frazon (logike ne povas ekzisti pekuloj senpekaj).

Tamen en la kazo de "krei lingvon bazitan/bazita sur Esperanto", mi klare preferus la solvon kun "bazitan". Oni ja volas esprimi, ke la lingvo estas bazita sur Esperanto, ne nur ke ĝi estis bazita sur Esperanto tuj post sia kreiĝo.

Answer (score 3):

La ĝusta frazo estas: `Mi kreis lingvon bazitan sur Esperanto.`
`Bazita` estas adjektiva participo, kaj adjektivo povas priskribi nur substantivon - en tiu frazo, `lingvon`. Tiel, `bazita` postulas la akuzativon.

Se oni volus ke la verbo estu priskribita, oni uzu adverbon. `Mi kreis surbaze de Esperanto.`

Fonto: http://www.esperanto.mv.ru/Seppik/lec09.html

Comment: Se mi memoras gxuste, la adverbaj participoj cxiam rilatas al la subjekto de la frazo, do "Mi kreis bazite sur Esperanto" signifas, ke mi estis bazita sur Esperanto kiam mi kreis.

Answer (score 2):

La ĝusta formo estas kun la akuzativo.

Mi ne pensas, ke ĝi rilatas al perverba priskribo, ĉar la participo priskribas la substantivon, enkondukante subpropozicion.

Comment: Kvankam mi konsentas kun vi, estus bone havi iun referencon aŭ ekzemplan citaĵon por esti pli konvinka.

Comment: Mi ne konsideris la perverban priskribon en la kazo de ‘krei’ laŭ la respondo de Marcos. Li tute pravas. Kutime, se ne temas pri perverba priskribo, tiam simple temas pri la kazkongrueco de la adverbo kaj substantivo. (Do tial mi elektis la formon kun akuzativo.)